# Unable to auth Microsoft 365 email with OAuth2 for daemon apps

Tags: asp.net, outlook, office365, azure-ad-msal, mailkit

I'm building daemon apps that read the mailbox and converted into ticket issue into our app. This app will connect to M365 mail server through IMAP/POP3 protocol using OAuth2 for authentication. I use MailKit for fetching email. It supports OAuth2 by default. It requires the access token only as password replacement.
What've I done

Register the app using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-app-registration). With the following details

1. I choose to generate client secret instead of using certificate
2. Authentication is for *Accounts in this organizational directory only (single tenant)*
3. Treat application as a public client
4. API Permissions

   - Exchange: Mail.ReadWrite and granted for admin consent (application permission)
   - Microsoft Graph: User.Read (from default setup)

The rest is unchanged.

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using MailKit;
using MailKit.Search;
using MailKit.Security;

const string clientSecret = "xxx";
const string clientId = "yyy";
const string tenant = "zzz";
const string graphApi = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
const string mailApi = "https://outlook.office.com/";

var apiClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new System.Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}"))
    .Build();
string[] scopes = new[]
{
//    $"{graphApi}.default",

// based on docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth
//    $"{mailApi}IMAP.AccessAsUser.All",
//    $"{mailApi}POP.AccessAsUser.All",

// based on URI generated when adding permission
//    "https://outlook.office365.com/Mail.ReadWrite",

// trying to guess
//    $"{graphApi}.Mail.ReadWrite",
//    $"{graphApi}/Mail.ReadWrite",
};
var result = await apiClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
using (var mailClient = new MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient())
{
    await mailClient.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 993, true);
    var auth = new SaslMechanismOAuth2($"user.domain@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com", result.AccessToken);
    await mailClient.AuthenticateAsync(auth);
    var mailBox = await mailClient.GetFolderAsync("INBOX");
    await mailBox.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
    var ids = await mailBox.SearchAsync(SearchQuery.All);
    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        var message = await mailBox.GetMessageAsync(id);
        //message.Dump();
    }
}
```

I've tried for different type of scopes and end up with the following result:

1. Token acquired when using `$"{graphApi}.default"` but the mail authentication fails
2. The rest scope combinations are invalid: *AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope xxx is not valid.
   Trace ID: 210121ba-e915-417a-9220-ade2defd7800
   Correlation ID: e13c86c9-bb88-4326-9e38-39f3b7104a92
   Timestamp: 2020-08-26 08:00:14Z*

Any help will be appreciated. This's copy of question from original [MS docs repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-exchange-docs/issues/100).

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure this is applicable to your scenario but here goes:

We were facing the same issue (thus stumbling onto your post here) and resolved it by using a different flow for requesting the token in the first place. In addition to `client_id` and `client_secret`, we provide all the details for a **password** authentication for the user who's mailbox we want to access:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/[your tenantid]/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type=password
username=[username for mailbox]
password=[password for that user]
client_id=[application client id]
client_secret=[application_client_secret]
scope=https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All openid offline_access
```

(Skipping all the encoding, adding line breaks etc.)

Afterwards, connecting to the IMAP outlook.office365.com with XOAUTH2 for user [username for mailbox] and the token received worked seamlessly.

Comment: Apparently, saving the email's password is not an option, so does posting the password to M365

Comment: This did work for me; I created a post about this with code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72984691/how-to-use-mailkit-with-imap-for-exchange-with-oauth2-for-daemon-non-interacti/72984692#72984692

Answer (score 0):

In order to authenticate IMAP application, you must use https://outlook.office365.com/.default in the scope property in the body payload for the access token request.
Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#register-your-application